# Simplifying boolean algebra without using certain operations

Tags: functions, simplifying-expressions

when I use `Simplify` or `FullSimplify` in Mathematica it often simplifies it using all the existing boolean operations. For example, consider the following:

```
FullSimplify[! (x && y && z) && ! (x && ! y && ! z) && ! (! x && ! y && z)]
Simplify[! (x && y && z) && ! (x && ! y && ! z) && ! (! x && ! y && z)]
```

Both the code segment above are going to output the following:

```
! (x ⊻ z ⊻ (x && y) ⊻ (z && y) ⊻ (z && x && y))
```

I do not want the `Xor` gates in the solution. Is there a way we can give restrictions to the two functions, such that it gives the simplest possible formula but without using other gates except `Or`, `Not`, and `And`.

I've tried `BooleanMinimize` with "CNF" and "DNF", but these two things do not mean that the formula is the simplest (in terms of numbers of operation). I simply want a "Simplify" that does not use other operators except `Not`, `And`, and `Or`. Thanks!

Comment: You may not be aware of an optional argument to `Simplify` called `ExcludedForms`. That can let you tell `Simplify` that `Xor` cannot be considered as part of the solution. `Simplify` uses `LeafCount`, which is roughly a count of the number of symbols needed to write an expression, to determine what is simplest. Without using `Xor` I'm not sure I see any expression with fewer symbols that is equivalent to your problem. Can you show the simplest result with fewer symbols?

Comment: The expression may not be necessarily simpler than using `Xor`. However what I want here is that the "simplest possible form" without `Xor`. Which can be solved using `ExcludedForms` argument. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try giving [`Simplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify) a [`ComplexityFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexityFunction) option that discourages [`Xor`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Xor):

```
Simplify[
    !(x&&y&&z)&&!(x&&!y&&!z)&&!(!x&&!y&&z),
    ComplexityFunction->(LeafCount[#]+10000Count[#, _Xor,{0,Infinity}]&)
]
```

> (x && ! y && z) || (! x && (y || ! z)) || (y && ! z)

**Addendum**

*(The OP asked about another expression)*

I don't know which boolean transformations are built in to [`Simplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify)/[`FullSimplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullSimplify), but you can add more with the option [`TransformationFunctions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformationFunctions). So:

```
FullSimplify[
    !u && !v && !w && !x,
    ComplexityFunction -> (LeafCount[#]+10000Count[#, _Xor,{0,Infinity}]&),
    TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, BooleanConvert[#,"OR"]&}
]

(* !(u || v || w || x) *)
```

Comment: This did the trick and does exactly what I want it to do! Thank you.

Although for some reason it does not always give out the "simplest". Most notably there are a lot of cases where this does not "simplify" using De Morgan's laws, it keeps `(!u && !v && !w && !x)` while in fact it can be simplified to `!(u || v || w || x)`, assuming that `LeafCount[!u] = 2` (due to the terms `!u` and `u`)... Is my understandingof `LeafCount` wrong?

Answer (score 2):

perhaps [`BooleanMinimize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BooleanMinimize.html)?

```
BooleanMinimize[! (x && y && z) && ! (x && ! y && ! z) && ! (! x && ! y && z)]
```

> (x && ! y && z) || (! x && y) || (! x && ! z) || (y && ! z)

```
BooleanMinimize[! (x && y && z) && ! (x && ! y && ! z) && ! (! x && ! y && z), "CNF"]
```

> (! x || ! y || ! z) && (! x || y || z) && (x || y || ! z)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however this just converts them into CNF and DNF instead of simplifying the formula as minimal as possible. Consider If I try to minimize `(x || (y && t)) && z` then using `BooleanMinimize` gives  `(t || x) && (x || y) && z` and `(t && y && z) || (x && z)` for "CNF" and "DNF" respectively. Which is more complex (has more repeated terms) than the original formula.